# How to convert a list of strings to a list of regexes

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, regex, list

I'm using Javascript and I'm importing data from a .txt file and I have all the elements from the .txt file in a list but I want to turn that list of strings into a list of regexes.

Lets say that for example I have the list: `["abc", "def", "ghi"]`
I want to turn that into the list: `[/abc/g, /def/g, /ghi/g]`

I have figured out how to turn the entire list into a single regex, but my goal is to have each element from the list to strings correspond to an element in the list of regexes.

Here's what I have right now which turns everything from the list of strings into one regex:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var myList = fs.readFileSync("./files/mytextfile.txt", "utf-8")
myList = myList.split("\n");
var myListRegex = new RegExp(myList.join("\n"), 'g');
```

Using the same example list above, if I were to print `myListRegex`, it would result in the following:

```
/abc
def
ghi/g
```

when I want it to print this:

```
[/abc/g, /def/g, /ghi/g]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing now is splitting things, and then putting it back to how it was so this `new RegExp(myList, 'g');` is identical to what you.

What you need to do is split `myList` and map over it creating a `RegExp` in each index of the array.

```
myList = myList.split("\n");
var myListRegex = myList.map((expression) => new RegExp(expression, 'g'));
```

Answer (score 0):

const myList = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
const rez = myList.reduce((prev, curr) => [...prev, new RegExp(curr, 'g')], [] as RegExp[])